# Keyboard layout order: last language is always the same

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use Ubuntu 13.04 with Unity.

I have 3 keyboard layouts: **English, Russian** and **Ukrainian**, and I want to set the switching shortcut to "Caps to first, Shift + Caps to last". The problem is that the last layout is always **Ukrainian**, regardless of order set in system settings (*All Settings -> Keyboard Layout*).

How do I make **Russian** the last layout so that it would be turned on by Shift + Caps?

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? When you say system settings do you mean in _Language Support_ or _Keyboard Layout?_

Comment: @chaskes updated my question. By the way, in *Language Support* I have only English, so it doesn't seem to affect anything.